# What is the etymology of the hstore datatype in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, hstore

Where did the datatype get its name? Hash store?

Comment: I'd suggest writing a mail to the authors.  Ther addresses can be found at the bottom of the [documentation page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/hstore.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The name of the additional module [`hstore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html) is derived from "hash store", because it was inspired by perl hash.
Oleg Bartunov and Teodor Sigaev - the authors of the module - say so [in their presentation here](http://www.sai.msu.su/%7Emegera/postgres/talks/hstore-pgcon-2013.pdf):

> Hstore — key/value storage (inspired by perl hash)